# Spring Boot tests: exclude one specific @Configuration class without using the @Profile annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test, spring-context

My situation is this: I have a `@SpringBootApplication` class that defines some beans and configurations that are needed both at runtime and during tests, and (in the same package) a `@Configuration` class that defines the application's own beans.
In unit tests, there are several of those beans that cannot be initialized and that I need to re-define and (partially) mock in a `@TestConfiguration` class.

Now, using the `@Profile` annotation would easily solve my problem but I'd prefer not writing any test-related code in the main application code. That includes the `"test"` profile in that annotation (or, well, `"!test"` I guess). Also I've read that using it to manage beans like this is an anti-pattern.

Here's some pseudo-code to make things clearer before saying what I tried:

Application class:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        }
        
        // overrides some configuration methods and default Spring beans
    }
```

Configuration class with the app's own beans:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class BeansConfiguration {
        
        @Bean
        BeanInterface1 bean1(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new BeanClass1(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        BeanInterface2 bean2(SomeOtherDependency otherDep) {
            return new BeanClass2(otherDep);
        }
        
        // other beans...
    }
```

Test configuration class that redefines these beans:

```java
    @TestConfiguration
    public class TestBeansConfiguration {
        
        @Bean
        @Primary
        BeanInterface1 bean1(DataSource dataSource) {
            // partial mock of the "BeanClass1" class, with a lot of custom code for tests
            return new TestBeanClass1(dataSource);
        }
        
        @Bean
        @Primary
        BeanInterface2 bean2(SomeOtherDependency otherDep) {
            return new TestBeanClass2(otherDep);// same here
        }
        
        // other beans more or less like this...
    }
```

Annotations on the abstract test class that is extended by most test classes:

```java
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public abstract class MyTestClass {
        // ...
    }
```

If you noticed the `@Primary` annotation on the test beans: it would work if I didn't have some beans in the `BeansConfiguration` class that completely fail to initialize and throw an exception in the test environment...

Now, before you ask me "why aren't you mocking these beans instead?" it's because this application didn't have Spring, previously. There was A LOT of test code in the "manual mocks" that were made, that can't just be thrown away. I've already adapted all such code to work in `@SpringBootTest`s, but I'm having trouble here initializing the Spring context.

One thing that I tried was defining the "classes" field in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation like so:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApplication.class, TestBeansConfiguration.class },
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Unfortunately it seems that the `BeansConfiguration` class is still found and used because I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'bean1' defined in com.example.TestBeansConfiguration:
Cannot register bean definition

[Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false;
lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true;
factoryBeanName=testBeansConfiguration; factoryMethodName=bean1; initMethodName=null;
destroyMethodName=(inferred);

defined in com.example.TestBeansConfiguration] for bean 'bean1': There is already

[Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false;
lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
factoryBeanName=beansConfiguration; factoryMethodName=bean1; initMethodName=null;
destroyMethodName=(inferred);

defined in class path resource [com/example/BeansConfiguration.class]] bound.
```

(I've formatted the error message to make it easier to read)

I've also tried defining an `ApplicationContextInitializer` class to try to manually exclude the `BeansConfiguration` class, like so:

```java
    public class ConfigExcludingContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(BeansConfiguration.class, null);
        }
    }
```

```java
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMainConfiguration.class, TestSpringConfiguration.class}, 
            initializers = ConfigExcludingContextInitializer.class)
```

But the result is the same.

I'd really like to leave the `@Profile` annotation as a last resource. Is there really no other easy way to exclude a specific `@Configuration` class from unit tests?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a misconception about `@Primary`. If multiple beans of the same type are defined, it does not mean that the one with `@Primary` will be created while the non-primary are ignored. `@Primary` is just useful for injection by type (e.g. `@Autowired`) which you have multiple beans of the same type defined but no `@Qualifier` are used to specify which bean to inject , then the `@Primary` one will be chosen to inject.

The current exception `BeanDefinitionOverrideException` is because you define multiple beans with the same bean name. It is not allowed because bean name is required to be a unique identifier.

You can configure `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` such that spring will not throw exception if it detects a bean with the same name is already defined before. Instead , it will override
the previous one with the current one.

Meaning that change to the following should solve your problem :

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"}
        , classes = {MyApplication.class, TestBeansConfiguration.class})
public class AppTest {


}
```

The bean processing order are based on the order of the context classes that are specified in `@SpringBootTest` .So beans defined due to the `TestBeansConfiguration` will override those due to `MyApplication` in case they have the same bean name.

Comment: I did not say that I thought that the non-primary beans don't get created. I said that the @Primary annotation would solve my problems if some beans didn't fail to initialize because I know that they wouldn't have impacted the tests when not used, anyway.

Comment: For the rest, thank you, I hadn't tried the `allow-bean-definition-overriding` property yet because I thought it wasn't useful in this case but actually I had misunderstood how it worked. Now all the test beans have the same names as the real ones and they do replace them successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the test configuration class is getting instanced and the beans are available to be injected. For test configuration classes I've needed to use import annotation to describe which test configuration classes to use.

For example, to include the test-only configurations that I have under my test directory, I use the import like here:

```
@Slf4j
@Import({ DynamoDbLocalServerConfig.class, RestMockServerConfig.class, DynamoDbTestClientConfig.class,
        TestKafkaTemplateConfig.class })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = PodsProcessorApplication.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093", "port=9093" },
        topics = { PROCESS_MARKER, PROCESS_MARKER_DEAD_LETTER })
```

Comment: Yeah it was getting instanced because otherwise I wouldn't have that conflict between beans of the same type (at least when specifying the test configuration class in the "classes" property of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. Without that, I would get an exception even sooner due to some of the non-test beans failing to initialize).

Answer (score 0):

You say you have two configuration classes, each class contains definitions of some beans, but probably you've decided to unify them into one configuration class for some business reason...

So here is my suggestion:

Use `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on your configuration classes. The property will make sense because it can turn on / off some **business feature**

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="myFeature1", hasValue=true, matchIfMissing=true)
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationA {
   ....
}

@ConditionalOnProperty(name="myFeature2", hasValue=true, matchIfMissing=true)
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationB {
   ....
}
```

In runtime it will be resolved to be "true" and load all the beans.

In tests, however, let's say you want to exclude beans defined in `MyConfigurationB` from being loaded

So define `src/test/resources/application.yml` (or use any other way of property definitions in tests) where you you can write something like this:

```
myFeature2=false
```

Now all beans from `MyConfigurationB` won't be loaded at all

Comment: "but probably you've decided to unify them into one configuration class for some business reason" No I didn't, I wrote the pseudo-code and it has 2 separate (non-test) configuration classes, the `@SpringBootApplication` one and the `@Configuration` one. Anyway, there are no beans that need to be conditionally disabled outside of tests, and I won't use the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation to disable beans during tests only. That would mean writing test-related code in the main app code, and I don't want to do it. But thank you anyway for helping.